# How can i update data using a form and useRef hooks?

Tags: reactjs

I am building a simple todo app. I am stuck figuring out how to edit those todos using the form. In another component I have a function which I am passing through props which updates the global state. I am able to pass the input fields data that the user selected to be able to update it.

How can i update the submitted values which are passed through props?

```
const TodoForm = (props) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(null);

  const titleInputRef = useRef();
  const descriptionInputRef = useRef();

  function submitHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const titleInputValue = titleInputRef.current.value;
    const descriptionInputValue = descriptionInputRef.current.value;

    const inputData = {
      title: titleInputValue,
      description: descriptionInputValue,
      id: Date.now(),
      completed: false,
    };

    props.submitInputHandler(inputData);
    e.target.reset();
  }

  return (
    <div className="col-span-2 text-center">
      <h1 className="text-xl mb-2">Nueva tarea</h1>


      <form className="space-y-2" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <label htmlFor="title" className="block">
          Titulo
        </label>
        <input
          ref={titleInputRef}
          type="text"
          id="title"
        />
        <label htmlFor="description" className="block">
          Descripcion
        </label>
        <textarea
          ref={descriptionInputRef}
          name="descripcion"
          id=""
          cols="25"
          rows="5"
        ></textarea>
        <button >
          Click
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Update the input values after the form is submitted?

Comment: Yes, that is why I am trying to accomplish

Comment: use `ref.current.value = null || ''`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want to change the value directly.

In this case you could change the **value** property of the input reference directly from the **ref.current** like so:

```
titleInputRef.current.value = 'Some value'
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use states for updating?

Comment: Not always. For optimization purpose you can use ref. If you need your component to show to the user the up-to-date data then you have to use state (because as soon as you make updates to state, React knows that and re-renders your component)

Comment: Thanks.. let me try it. I'll get back to you with the results.